# remove marker - Google Map - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i have the below code
but when add new marker i want removing old marker
please help me about this
I searched for a lot of resources, but unfortunately I didn't get them

```
 var map;

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(45.567846, 25.396878);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function init() {

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: center,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var  timerId = setInterval( function(){

makeRequest('GPS/get_locations.php', function(data) {

var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
displayLocation(data[i]);
}
});

}, 2000);

}


function displayLocation(location) {

var content =   '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>'
+ location.branch +" "+ location.serial
+ '</strong>'

+ '<br/>'     +"User: "+ location.user
// + '<br/>'     +"Serial: "+ location.serial
+ '<br/>'     +"Date: "+ location.date
+ '<br/>'     +"Time: "+ location.time 
+ '<br/>'     +"Lat: "+ location.lat 
+ '<br/>'     +"Lng: "+ location.lng +'</div>'
+ '<br/>'     +"Speed: "+ location.speed +'</div>';
// + '<br/>'     +"Credit: "+ location.credit +'</div>'
// + '<br/>'     +"Charge: "+ location.charge +'</div>';


if (parseInt(location.lat) == 0) {
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location.address }, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: results[0].geometry.location,
title: location.name
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(content);
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

/* Save geocoding result to the Database
var url =   'set_coords.php?id=' + location.id
+ '&amp;lat=' + results[0].geometry.location.lat()
+ '&amp;lon=' + results[0].geometry.location.lng();

makeRequest(url, function(data) {
if (data.responseText == 'OK') {
// Success
}
});*/
}
});
} else {

var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: position,
title: location.name
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(content);
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
}
}

var  timerId = setInterval( function(){
init();
}, 60000);

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
} else {
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
}
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
callback(request);
}
}
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
}
//]]>
```

i have the below code
but when add new marker i want removing old marker
please help me about this
I searched for a lot of resources, but unfortunately I didn't get them

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple. Declare your **marker variable** as null outside of the function displayLocation():

> var marker = null

Then add this condition:

```
//Your code//
/////////////
if (marker != null){
  marker.setMap(null)
}
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  position: position,
  title: location.name
});
/////Your rest of the code//////
```

Complete code is here:

```
var map;
var marker = null;
var center = new google.maps.LatLng(45.567846, 25.396878);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function init() {

var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: center,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var  timerId = setInterval( function(){

makeRequest('GPS/get_locations.php', function(data) {

var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
displayLocation(data[i]);
}
});

}, 2000);

}


function displayLocation(location) {

var content =   '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>'
+ location.branch +" "+ location.serial
+ '</strong>'

+ '<br/>'     +"User: "+ location.user
// + '<br/>'     +"Serial: "+ location.serial
+ '<br/>'     +"Date: "+ location.date
+ '<br/>'     +"Time: "+ location.time 
+ '<br/>'     +"Lat: "+ location.lat 
+ '<br/>'     +"Lng: "+ location.lng +'</div>'
+ '<br/>'     +"Speed: "+ location.speed +'</div>';
// + '<br/>'     +"Credit: "+ location.credit +'</div>'
// + '<br/>'     +"Charge: "+ location.charge +'</div>';


if (parseInt(location.lat) == 0) {
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location.address }, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

if (marker != null){
  marker.setMap(null)
}
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: results[0].geometry.location,
title: location.name
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(content);
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

/* Save geocoding result to the Database
var url =   'set_coords.php?id=' + location.id
+ '&amp;lat=' + results[0].geometry.location.lat()
+ '&amp;lon=' + results[0].geometry.location.lng();

makeRequest(url, function(data) {
if (data.responseText == 'OK') {
// Success
}
});*/
}
});
} else {

var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lng));

if (marker != null){
   marker.setMap(null)
 }
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,
position: position,
title: location.name
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.setContent(content);
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
}
}

var  timerId = setInterval( function(){
init();
}, 60000);

function makeRequest(url, callback) {
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
} else {
request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
}
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
callback(request);
}
}
request.open("GET", url, true);
request.send();
}
//]]>
```

Comment: What's the problem you are facing now?

Comment: I put the code after displayLocation():, but there is no response

Comment: No you should put the code inside the displayLocation(), Only variable declaration should be outside the function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help
  I replaced your code exactly. It has the same result and has not changed
Each time a new record is added to the database, a new marker is added but the previous marker is not deleted

Comment: Can you see in the console or view page source that the code is changed? Because sometime it is cached if your using .js file

Comment: OK I got it. I have edited my answer again. You can copy paste again. This time it should work. We were missing the code in the else condition.

Comment: I deleted the cache and refreshed it.
And I put the code this way, but I didn't see anything on the console:if (marker != null){
    console.log("a");
  marker.setMap(null)
}

Comment: That's because your else condition is executing. I have updated my code. Try the edited answer

Comment: Thankful
It works now
But only the last amount of our marker returns
Eliminates the rest
I already had 5 markers
Now only the last amount of XML is returned

Comment: Previously, I had 5 markers on the map
After editing the code, only 1 marker is displayed

Comment: That's because at one time the variable marker will hold only one object. Before edit you were declaring seperate object for every marker. If you want to remove only last marker and other 5 markers should be there. Then you have to user Arrays. Insert all marker objects into array and then remove the last inserted element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance. So far, everything is fine and that's great. I made good progress with your help.
About arrays, help and edit the code for me? Thank you very much

Comment: You should try it yourself and have to do some research.